# Getting "NameError: name 'a' is not defined" even though variable 'a' is available holding an integer value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a very small function which is expected to returns the parameters passed while calling it. Instead I'm getting NameError: name 'a' is not defined

This code snippet indeed works when 'b' is given an integer value

```
def func(a,b,c):
    return a,b,c

result = func(a=5, c=15, b=25)
print(result)
```

but when the same is assigned the sum of 'a' and 'c', NameError is appearing.

```
def func(a,b,c):
    return a,b,c

result = func(a=5, c=15, b=a+c)
print(result)


"NameError: name 'a' is not defined"
```

Comment: `a` is not defined in `b=a+c`

Comment: but 'a' is already having value 5 !!!

Comment: I think you're confusing named arguments for assignments, since they both use the equals `=` sign.

Comment: yeah you are right @wjandrea, I got confused for a moment with the equals sign! Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using named parameters when calling the function, but you are not really declaring the variables, so `a` and `b` are in fact undefined when you try to pass them as a value for `c`. You need to do the following:

```
a=5
c=15
result = func(a=a, c=c, b=a+c)
```

Comment: so does that mean, for b=a+c, value of 'a' and 'c' are unknown variable and 'b' treats them as if they don't exist at all in the program !!

Comment: Yes, that's it. They don't exist as variables, you are just using a special notation for passing the values when calling the function, that allows you to alter the order of them.

Answer (score 2):

`a`, `b` and `c` in this case are not variables but argument names (they only become variables in the function's scope, not where you call them), that's why something like this:

```
b = 25
result = func(a=5, c=15, b=b)
```

works, although `b=b` looks like it doesn't make any sense.

Also, this *won't* work:

```
result = func(a=5, c=15, b=25)
print(a)
```

because `a` is not a variable in this scope.

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
func(a=5)
```

a is not a variable, its an argument, which means you cannot access it outside of the function.
Which means when you do:

```
func(a=5, b=a)
```

It will try to find a variable named a which doesnt exist.
Instead just set the variables before the function call and it should work:

```
def func(a,b,c):
    return a,b,c

a=5
c=15
b=a+c

result = func(a=a, c=c, b=b)
print(result)
```

Comment: Danke @Kevin Müller